# How can I make USSD call from laptop?

Tags: gsm

Don't know if I'm in the right place...
Is is possible to create a software that will use a laptop (a real one, not a hybrid pc) to place ussd quries ? I saw stuff about GSM modem but don't know... 
What I want to do is to create a desktop application that will make ussd requests to my gsm telephony provider and manage the ussd response... Don't want to use smartphone also (I already tried it works but not helping me...)

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. USSD is a mobile network protocol, and requires that you are connected to a mobile network. Smart phone obviously are, but laptops generally aren't.

However, if your laptop has a 3G/4G modem (either internally or externally via USB), then it might be possible. A more accurate answer would depend on the exact modem model and your OS.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783706/programmatic-access-to-ussd-from-the-windows-10-desktop for the specific case of modems supportd by Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This works very well for SMS and USSD:

http://support.black-it.eu/en/products/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm

Comment: IDK why anyone would downvote this answer. It seems to be the only valid answer on this site AFAICS

Comment: I hope it really works as it says it is. It looks like the one I'm using. Hopefully if I can interract with it with an API it'll be perfect. I'll check it out and accept the answer it that really works. Thank you isg

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/513819)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

http://support.black-it.eu/en/products/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm

Works according as given by @user212688

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample project from official ms learn:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/ussdprotcol/

It does exactly what you asked for.